# How can I format a javascript using java?

Tags: javascript, java, format, indentation

I'm trying to write a javascript from java application.
Currently I'm using

```
try {
    Writer  writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path....
```

My question is: How to format the result code with correct indentation?

Comment: do you want to write code to indent the code, make something like [[http://jsbeautifier.org/](http://jsbeautifier.org/)] or know about resources like [[http://jsbeautifier.org/](http://jsbeautifier.org/)] ?

Comment: i need to use java code to indent my javascript but i don't know if it's possible